# django heroku when debug is false and allowed host is set i get still a 500 page - how i have to set my settings that i come to my Startpage

Tags: django, debugging, heroku

i load a new app to heroku and then i made a customer domain www.mydomain.de. if i let in my settings.py the DEBUG on TRUE everything work fine, but in production thats not so good. 
if debug is flase and i set the ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.myDomain.de'] but i get then a 500 page. Why? (see in my code)
So how i have to change my settings.py or heroku that the page work. Thank you for your help!

```
   import os
   import django_heroku


    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')



    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = False

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mydomain.de']


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Website',

    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',


    ]



    ROOT_URLCONF = 'gettingstarted.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
              ],
           },
        },
     ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gettingstarted.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
       }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
     {
        'NAME': 
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
     },
     { 
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
      },
      {
         'NAME': 
      'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
      },
      {
        'NAME': 
      'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
       },
       ]


     # Internationalization
     # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

     LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

     TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

     USE_I18N = True

   USE_L10N = True

   USE_TZ = True


   # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
   # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'



   MAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
   EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
   EMAIL_PORT = '587'
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_ADRESS')
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PW')
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


   django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Internal Server Error: /

```
ValueError at /
Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '/Website/Images/BLogoXSKopie.ico'

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://www.mydomain.de/
Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Executable: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path: ['/app', '/app/.heroku/python/bin', '/app', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time: Mon, 9 Apr 2018 07:46:11 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'Website']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
 35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
 128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
 126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/Website/views.py" in Mainpage
 16.     return render(request, "Mainpage.html")

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
 36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
 62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
 61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
 167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
 910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
 155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
 167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
 943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
 910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in render
 106.         url = self.url(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in url
 103.         return self.handle_simple(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in handle_simple
 118.             return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in url
 155.         return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in _url
 134.                 hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in stored_name
 422.                 raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '/Website/Images/BLogoXSKopie.ico'
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES:

language = 'de-DE'
_ga = 'GA1.2.1466051518.1523211359'
_gid = 'GA1.2.1212963241.1523211359'


META:

HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip, deflate'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL = 'max-age=0'
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'close'
HTTP_CONNECT_TIME = '2'
HTTP_COOKIE = '.ASPXANONYMOUS=pDqwlMX30wEkAAAANTRhN2JlZDQtMmRiNC00ZTI0LTlmY2UtMzEzNmIwYzFjYmQw0; language=de-DE; _ga=GA1.2.1466051518.1523211359; _gid=GA1.2.1212963241.1523211359; csrftoken=MJ3LU4rZfeEE2qVpUaWflOiBznubip882CzVxVeTiIjTBTwryiFG8Wc3TCjrYojy'
HTTP_HOST = 'www.mydomain.de'
HTTP_TOTAL_ROUTE_TIME = '0'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS = '1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
HTTP_VIA = '1.1 vegur'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = '217.87.25.110'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT = '80'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO = 'http'
HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID = '2ac78d18-0d04-4252-9977-97d3a6e3ba09'
HTTP_X_REQUEST_START = '1523259971191'
PATH_INFO = '/'
QUERY_STRING = ''
RAW_URI = '/'
REMOTE_ADDR = '10.41.238.100'
REMOTE_PORT = '48100'
REQUEST_METHOD = 'GET'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
SERVER_NAME = '0.0.0.0'
SERVER_PORT = '30289'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'gunicorn/19.7.1'
gunicorn.socket = <socket.socket fd=10, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.17.86.50', 30289), raddr=('10.41.238.100', 48100)>
wsgi.errors = <gunicorn.http.wsgi.WSGIErrorsWrapper object at 0x7fec87fbfd68>
wsgi.file_wrapper = ''
wsgi.input = <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x7fec880262b0>
wsgi.multiprocess = True
wsgi.multithread = False
wsgi.run_once = False
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
wsgi.version = '(1, 0)'

Settings:
Using settings module gettingstarted.settings
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {}
ADMINS = "(('Florian', '**********************'),)"
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
APPEND_SLASH = True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = '********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
BASE_DIR = '/app'
CACHES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = '********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = 31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = []
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
DATABASES = {'default': {'NAME': 'de1n442gnd8p2c', 'USER': 'hlqkaoveswaped', 'PASSWORD': '********************', 'HOST': 'ec2-174-129-206-173.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'PORT': 5432, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600, 'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'}, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 1000
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG = False
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/html'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE = ''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = ''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = []
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*********************'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE = None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE = '********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler', 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0
FIXTURE_DIRS = []
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = None
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'Website']
INTERNAL_IPS = []
LANGUAGES = [('af', 'Afrikaans'), ('ar', 'Arabic'), ('ast', 'Asturian'), ('az', 'Azerbaijani'), ('bg', 'Bulgarian'), ('be', 'Belarusian'), ('bn', 'Bengali'), ('br', 'Breton'), ('bs', 'Bosnian'), ('ca', 'Catalan'), ('cs', 'Czech'), ('cy', 'Welsh'), ('da', 'Danish'), ('de', 'German'), ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'), ('el', 'Greek'), ('en', 'English'), ('en-au', 'Australian English'), ('en-gb', 'British English'), ('eo', 'Esperanto'), ('es', 'Spanish'), ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'), ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'), ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'), ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'), ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'), ('et', 'Estonian'), ('eu', 'Basque'), ('fa', 'Persian'), ('fi', 'Finnish'), ('fr', 'French'), ('fy', 'Frisian'), ('ga', 'Irish'), ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'), ('gl', 'Galician'), ('he', 'Hebrew'), ('hi', 'Hindi'), ('hr', 'Croatian'), ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'), ('hu', 'Hungarian'), ('ia', 'Interlingua'), ('id', 'Indonesian'), ('io', 'Ido'), ('is', 'Icelandic'), ('it', 'Italian'), ('ja', 'Japanese'), ('ka', 'Georgian'), ('kab', 'Kabyle'), ('kk', 'Kazakh'), ('km', 'Khmer'), ('kn', 'Kannada'), ('ko', 'Korean'), ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'), ('lt', 'Lithuanian'), ('lv', 'Latvian'), ('mk', 'Macedonian'), ('ml', 'Malayalam'), ('mn', 'Mongolian'), ('mr', 'Marathi'), ('my', 'Burmese'), ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'), ('ne', 'Nepali'), ('nl', 'Dutch'), ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'), ('os', 'Ossetic'), ('pa', 'Punjabi'), ('pl', 'Polish'), ('pt', 'Portuguese'), ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'), ('ro', 'Romanian'), ('ru', 'Russian'), ('sk', 'Slovak'), ('sl', 'Slovenian'), ('sq', 'Albanian'), ('sr', 'Serbian'), ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'), ('sv', 'Swedish'), ('sw', 'Swahili'), ('ta', 'Tamil'), ('te', 'Telugu'), ('th', 'Thai'), ('tr', 'Turkish'), ('tt', 'Tatar'), ('udm', 'Udmurt'), ('uk', 'Ukrainian'), ('ur', 'Urdu'), ('vi', 'Vietnamese'), ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'), ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI = ['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
LOCALE_PATHS = []
LOGGING = {'version': 1, 'disable_existing_loggers': False, 'formatters': {'verbose': {'format': '%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s funcname=%(funcName)s %(message)s', 'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}, 'simple': {'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'}}, 'handlers': {'null': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'class': 'logging.NullHandler'}, 'console': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'class': 'logging.StreamHandler', 'formatter': 'verbose'}}, 'loggers': {'testlogger': {'handlers': ['console'], 'level': 'INFO'}}}
LOGGING_CONFIG = 'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None
MAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
MANAGERS = []
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE = "('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')"
MIGRATION_MODULES = {}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING = 0
PASSWORD_HASHERS = '********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = '********************'
PREPEND_WWW = False
ROOT_URLCONF = 'gettingstarted.urls'
SECRET_KEY = '********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = False
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = []
SECURE_SSL_HOST = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_FILE_PATH = None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE = 'gettingstarted.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND = 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = []
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = '/app/staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATES = [{'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 'DIRS': [], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS = []
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
TIME_FORMAT = 'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_ETAGS = False
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False
USE_TZ = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT = False
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gettingstarted.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'
```

Comment: Please make sure that `[*]` solve the problem then add your domain and debug

Comment: Ich habe auch versucht: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']  - no success

Comment: what's the output of your webservers error log?

Comment: where i can see that on herko?

Comment: There should be a console or log link somewhere. As I read the heroku django package, which you are using, it logs to console (https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/master/django_heroku/core.py)

Comment: `heroku logs`  and update your question with output

Comment: add `ADMINS = (('Your name', 'Your@EMAIL'),)` to your `settings.py` so you get the Traceback sent to your email

Answer (score 3):

Heroku does not support djangos default static file serving in production. Please see the [Heroku Docs: Django and Static Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) on how to change your `settings.py`. Also have a eye on this subtopic [Django Assets: Collectstatic during builds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#collectstatic-during-builds).

Comment: nothing changed if i do it so... 
Anyone have a settings template where I can see it how that have to look like (where DEBUG = FALSE) ??